# Transferring Music from iPod to iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music, ipod, extract

Is there a way for me to transfer music from my iPod to my iTunes?  Say, if I accidentally deleted some music on my computer but I have the files on my iPod?

Comment: Here's a good article on that topic: [Copying Content from your iPod to your Computer](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/copying-music-from-ipod-to-computer/P0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put your iPod into Disk Mode, you can drag all the files to your music folder on your computer, and then let iTunes sort it out. Just make sure you check "Keep iTunes music folder organized."

I hope this helps.

Comment: And in case you're using Windows, the folder you need is `\iPod_Control\Music` (it's hidden by default)

Comment: This will work for non-iOS iPod devices.  For iOS devices (i.e. the iPod Touch), you'll need something like  i-FunBox or DiskAid to access the device's file system.  In all of the above cases, the filenames will be non-sensical (e.g. OQJE.mp3).  Alternatively you can use MediaMonkey to access the file system and automatically rename the files to something meaninful (see http://www.mediamonkey.com/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=3 ).

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you can use [iDump](http://www.escsoft.com/idump.php) to extract songs from the iPod then throw them into iTunes.

> This program will allow you transfer your songs from your iPod to a PC, iDump does come wrapped in installer but you can simply drop the .exe in the root directory on your iPod and run it from there.

On OS X there is [expod](http://expod.joynt.net/):

> expod is a small utility for getting songs off your iPod. iTunes does a fantastic job of copying music onto an iPod, but lacks the ability to go the other way. With expod you can copy any or all of your songs (or videos) off your iPod, using whatever file naming convention you like.

… and [podUp](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23586/podup), both free as well:

> podUp is an application which copies all your music files from your iPod to a folder of your choosing, without having anything to do with iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

Putting your iPod in Disk mode will work for iPods other than the iPod Touch.  For the iPod Touch and iPhone, you'll need to use a tool that is capable of reading the iPod Touch/iPhone database.

One such tool is MediaMonkey -- the free version can handle this.  Here are the [instructions.](http://www.mediamonkey.com/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=3)

Disclosure: I work on MediaMonkey, but happen to feel that it's the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows I use [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/)

On Mac I use [expod](http://expod.joynt.net/)

And just in case anyone asks, both works with iPhones and iPod Touches (I personally tried up to firmware version 3.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

For the Mac there's a shareware app called [Senuti](http://www.fadingred.com/senuti/) that probably does exactly the same thing as the free apps, but has nice instructional videos on the web site, and possibly a more Appleish user interface.