# Copy from Ipod to Itunes

Tags: itunes, ipod

I know it is possible to [copy music from an iPod to iTunes](https://superuser.com/questions/15420/transferring-music-from-ipod-to-itunes). Is it possible to also copy playlists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/about/) (Windows) can do this.

> SharePod is easy to use and works!
>   Heres some of the main features:
>
> - Add & remove music and videos from your iPod
> - Add, remove and edit playlists
> - Add & remove album art
> - View and backup photos
> - Copy music, videos **and playlists from your iPod to PC**
> - Import music/videos into your iTunes library, including playlists and
>     ratings
> - Tag editing
> - Drag n' drop to and from Explorer
> - Simple, clean interface
> - Quick to load and use with no unnessary complicated features
> - Support for iPhone and iTouch (Thanks to Nikias Bassen, Paul Sladen,
>     Jonathan Beck, and Christophe Fergeau
>     for making this possible)

If you're on a Mac I believe you can do this via iTunes.

- Plug your iPod in and launch iTunes
- Select your iPod from the left pane
- along the bottom right edge of iTunes are a bunch of icons. Click on the one that looks like an iPod. It'll bring up this configuration window:

[image]

- Click **manually manage songs and playlists**, then you can go back to the iTunes window and drag them around.