# How do I recover my iTunes music after a computer restoration?

Tags: itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transferring Music from iPod to iTunes?](https://superuser.com/questions/15420/transferring-music-from-ipod-to-itunes)

I recently had to restore my computer and lost my iTunes! Now when I down load iTunes again. How can I keep the music that's on my ipod without deleting it!

Comment: @Kyle - I agree.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes doesn't remove music on your iPod without you telling it to (e.g. by activating Sync). You can keep it on there indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Try Winamp for syncing the ipod, 
afaik it does not lead to deletion of existing files on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Senuti](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14982/senuti), it is freeware.

> Senuti is a simple utility that makes transferring songs from an iPod
>   to your computer quick and easy. It reads information from the
>   iTunesDB file located on your iPod in order to quickly retrieve
>   information on all of the songs on your iPod. Senuti is currently
>   under active development and many features will be added in the
>   future.