# Extracting movies from an iPod

Tags: itunes, sync, ipod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transferring Music from iPod to iTunes?](https://superuser.com/questions/15420/transferring-music-from-ipod-to-itunes)

I have a number of movies on an iPod classic. If you sync an iPod with iTunes, it will erase all data that is not in the iTunes library.

What's the best way to source this?

Comment: So, if there's a number of tools available, what have you already tried? Are you using Windows or OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:Set your ipod to enable disc use (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1478)

Step 2:Attach your iPod and connect it to the computer and [enable hidden files view](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/how-to-see-hidden-files-in-windows/) and go to "iPod Control" folder, you will find your movies there.